# ASCII only connection to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Let's imagine I have a legacy application that I would like to connect to a modern SQL Server. This legacy application only understands ASCII, but the SQL Server contains Unicode data in `nvarchar` column types. Is there an option I can set at the user or connection level to have SQL Server map extended characters back into their nearest ASCII equivalent? E.g. any of à á â ã ã ã in a value returned in a query would be return as plain `a`, any of è é ê ë would be plain `e` and so on.

Comment: There is no session-level setting that will automatically convert Unicode to ASCII. Does the legacy app only use ASCII characters 0-127 or does it use a code page to map characters in the 128-255 range? What programming language and client API are you using?

Comment: I suspected that would be the case. I suppose I could write an ODBC shim to `iconv()` the result set as it goes through. Thanks :-)

Comment: That depends on the capability of the specific version of the ODBC driver on the client. If that version supports Unicode, it will be able to [convert automatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client-odbc-results/autotranslation-of-character-data?view=sql-server-2017) to the client code page.